# Object Lifetime, Windows Forms, and Dependency Injection (Windsor)

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, object-lifetime

**Quick Background:** I've finished (mostly) reading Mark Seemann's "Depdendency Injection in .NET" and am ready to become a DI ninja. I've refactored my codebase to use constructor injection, wired up my objects using Windsor, and SUCCESS!

... except not. My program originally displayed several forms throughout it's lifetime, and this was originally accomplished by new()ing them all up as needed. However, now that I'm a NIT (ninja-in-training) I know that new() is evil and must be banished to the composition root.

**The problem:** My first end-to-end use test involved displaying my "main" window to the user. This window can be closed and a new version can be brought up again later. This worked fine in the post-DI codebase until it came time to display the form for a second time. crash. The form had already been disposed. In wiring up my DI container I told it to use the Form's class to implement a specific interface and as should be expected it gave that object a singleton lifetime.

**The question:** So I'm pretty sure the way to fix this is to not have a dependency on the interface that the form implemented, but rather have a dependency on a factory for that interface. This is where I'm confused on how to proceed.

My first thought is to create a factory with the same constructor signature as the form, store all of those dependencies, and then new() up a form whenever one is asked for. However, this feels like poor-man's DI and I've already gone through the hassle of registering all my stuff with the Windsor container. So that leads me to...

My second thought was to instead create a factory that takes the DI container as a dependency and then just .Resolve()s what I need each time (using the transient lifestyle this time). I suspect that I'd hook into the .Closed event and release there (following the Register-Resolve-Release pattern).

**The real question:** I like the idea of my second thought, but for some reason it feels like a hack. I don't know if that's because it is (and there is a better way) or if my spidey-senses just aren't tuned for DI yet. So, bottom line, is the "second thought" a valid approach or is it a code smell?

Also, if I use this approach with something that doesn't provide a way to hook into a "closed" event then how should I design the release mechanism such that the factory reminds/encourages me to release the object when done? (at some point I'll probably forget otherwise...)

Thanks!

Comment: What lifestyle strategy are you taking for your screens? How do you manage that?

Comment: Each "screen" or form will have a limited life span relative to the application (as in, it will start after the application starts and end before the application ends). I want each form to start out new and fresh when it's first shown. I then assume that I should Release it in the DI container once the form has been closed.

Comment: After thinking about the problem further I may have stumbled upon an accecptable answer. The reason that I didn't like the idea of using a Factory that contained the DI container was because I only wanted my composition root to have a dependency on the DI DLL (Windsor in this case). But it made sense to me that each factory be declaired in the same project as the item it created but I didn't want to have each project to reference the DI DLL. However, if I make the Factory Interface in the item's project and then implement that interface with my composition root then I get the best of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working for me while still keeping my lower layers unaware of the DI container was to create a factory interface at the lower layer, but then implement that factory at my composition root layer.

i.e.:

```
namespace MyApp.InterfaceLayer
{
    public interface IFormFactory
    {
        IForm GetForm();
    }
}
namespace MyApp.CompositionRoot
{
    class FormFactory : IFormFactory
    {
        Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer Container { get; set; }

        public FormFactory(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            Container = container;
        }
        public IForm GetForm()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<IForm>();
        }
    }
}
```

I would then of course register my form that implements `IForm` using a transient lifestyle and would register my container as an `IWindsorContainer`.

So far this has been working like a champ!

Comment: So how does the container what specific implementation you are looking for? I suppose you have multiple forms implementing IForm?

Comment: You have to register a concrete class that implements IForm with Windsor. This is done at the composition root (top layer).

Comment: Yes, I know - but you probably have more than one form in your project that must implement IForm?

Comment: Nope, just the one. Anytime an 'IForm' is resolved it will always resolve to the same instance (or at least the same concrete class, depending on lifetime). If you need to use a different 'IForm' elsewhere and you know ahead of time which one you need then you need to create some 'IOtherform : IForm' and register the new interface. If you don't know what one you need until runtime then you need to register an abstract factory, then during runtime resolve the abstract factory and then pass in the data needed to know which form it should create (which may use '.Resolve' on the DI container).